# How to move one of the maven multi-module projects to its own directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Springboot multi-module maven project.

Now I want to move one of the applications(module) to its own folder/project.

So far,

1. I created a new folder with its POM.xml
2. Copied my intended module to it, and made it a child module of the project's pom.
3. In my original project I ran `mvn package` to create jars of all the modules.
4. Copied these jars to a folder (./repo) inside the new project.

But now, I am unable to import dependencies from these JARs.

I have added this to the new project's POM

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>data-local</id>
    <name>data</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```